# Where can I find a foldable character sheet for The Dresden Files?

Tags: dresden-files, fate, character-sheets, diaspora

I saw a question on Area 51 for the proposed questions for this site about "What's the point of the foldable character sheet that is available for Diaspora?", and it was flagged as a good question, but it was never asked here, and I was wondering as I was listening to a podcast about the game what this 'foldable' character sheet that they were talking about was.

I did some research and found the answer- what a cool idea to have the pertinent information visible to the GM through the character sheet!  Is there such a sheet already available for The Dresden Files?  I looked for one, but my google-fu failed me.

I know I could make one, but wanted to see if there was one available before using my limited layout skills.

Comment: can you link to the other foldable character sheet, because i'm having a hard time understanding what you're talking about.  Also, the dfrpg website has some player resources up http://www.dresdenfilesrpg.com/downloads/

Comment: The actual link to the character sheet is http://www.phreeow.net/Diaspora/Diaspora%20character%20sheet%20con.pdf.  The link was found on Diaspora SRD site http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/diaspora-srd.html.

Comment: oh i see, it's got 2 fold points. that way you can have it look like -^ on the table, with one angle part looking towards the GM, on angle part looking towards you, and one part on the table so that you can write on it during the session.  from what i see on what you've provided you could just use that exact printout and not have any issues, except it doesn't show your refresh base, adjusted refresh, or skill points

Comment: @wraith808 Make that an answer.

Comment: I'm actually going to make a Word template for a customized one for Dresden Files... then I'll post it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I couldn't actually find a character sheet like this for The Dresden Files, I created my own.  Since I used assets from the Evil Hat character sheet, I submitted it to them first to make sure it's OK for me to distribute it; Fred Hicks has graciously given his permission for me to distribute these.

A PDF and PNG of the sheet is available [here](http://www.chuckdee.net/files/DFRPG-FoldableCharacterSheet.zip).

You can see some images of the foldable sheet in action below:

[image: Front of Character Sheet]

[image: Back of Character Sheet]